# AJAX javascript to update page titles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Like title says, when I load a different page through AJAX the title is not updating. The titles that should be loading are listed below..."Home", "About", and "FAQ".

I tried this, but that only changed the title to "undefined". What steps can I take to grab the title name from the code above and implement it?

```
var pageTitle = jQuery("input.page-title").val();
document.title = pageTitle;
```

HTML:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="./">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="./about">About</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="./contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: `jQuery("input.page-title")` selects all input elements that have the class `page-title`. I don't see any of those in your HTML, so that might be the problem.

Comment: where's the code that does the loading? Will clearly need to tie the title change to event handling for that. Also should show all your code that isn't working in it's full context. We don't know where you are calling that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your html posted, it seems like the following code would do it

```
var pageTitle = jQuery("li.active").children('a').html();
document.title = pageTitle;
```

This grabs the text out of the link where the parent is set to active.

Comment: This works, but only for the home page, probably because it is the active one to begin with. When going to the "About" or "FAQ" page, the page title is still shown as "Home"

Comment: @Jefferson yes, the code assumes that some other code was setting the right item to have the .active class.    If you don't yet have something to set that, maybe you can get the page name from the URL. like this: pageName=location.pathname.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]||'index';    then you could set the right item to be active, as well as set the pageTitle

Comment: ah I see, I wasn't sure how to grab the active page...what do I do with the pageName variable now? Does it go in the jQuery function?

Comment: @Jefferson well, I don't see your html anymore in your question, but you could select the one you want and make it active, something like jQuery('a:contains('+pageName+')').parent().addClass('active');  The idea is to find the link with text that matches the name of the page you are on and set it to active.  Then you wouldn't need the other jquery, you could just do document.title=pageName;   This all assumes that the html filename you're on is like about.html  or whatever.  Or is everything happening on index.html?

Comment: yeah I have separate files for about.html, etc but the main code is on index.html. I added back in the HTML to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.title = pageTitle;
```

Must work. So you difenetly have mistake in

```
jQuery("input.page-title").val();
```

Comment: how does this answer question?